# I want to delete a worksheet when I delete a row in another worksheet (EXCEL 2007)

Tags: excel, worksheet

In my workbook, I have a worksheet that contains a list of form-names, with each form-name in a separate row.  For each of these rows, there is a separate worksheet with that form-name containing information about that form.

I would like to include this functionality:

When the user deletes a row from the first worksheet, the corresponding worksheet is also deleted.

My initial approach tried using the Worksheet_Change event to trigger code to capture the form-name from the row deleted, and then to delete the worksheet with that name, but I cannot capture that data since the row is already deleted.

Is this functionality possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `selection change` to grab the sheetname for the row they are on, and the change event to delete the sheet.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim SheetName As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If SheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Cells(Target.Row, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub 'Inserted a row?
If Cells(Target.Row, 1) <> SheetName Then
    Worksheets(SheetName).Delete
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    SheetName = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
Else
    SheetName = ""
End If
End Sub
```

*I'm assuming your sheetname is in the 1st column - change the 1 in the `Cells(` reference if not*